# SSH Agent Forwarding with Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a RHEL "dev" server running Ansible behind a jumpbox.

I need to connect to the RHEL server from a Windows 10 machine using the VS Code Remote - SSH extension for Ansible development work. I am using Git Bash for SSH/*nix stuff.

The jumpbox has SSH port forwarding disabled - which as far as I know, will remain disabled.

I have copied the `agent-forwarding` public key to the jumpbox and the RHEL server. So, I am able to connect to the RHEL server via the jumpbox using SSH Agent Forwarding.

Here is what my SSH config file looks like.

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes

# Jump box
Host jump-box
    HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
    User test_user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/agent-forwarding

# RHEL server
Host rhel-dev
    HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
    User test_user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/agent-forwarding
```

Using this SSH config, from VS Code, I use `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...` and select `rhel-dev`.

On my first attempt, `rhel-dev` downloaded the binaries for vscode-server and installed it.

However, when trying to connect to this server from VS Code, I get the following error - `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`.

Here is the full log

```
Running remote connection script
Acquiring lock on /home/test_user/.vscode-server/bin/2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529/vscode-remote-lock.2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529Found existing installation at /home/test_user/.vscode-server/bin/2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529...
Found running server...

*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
*

Checking server status on port 42200 with wget
cc11e6e5-2b75-47ea-a727-62f738a7b5d9: start
sshAuthSock====
agentPort==42200==
webViewServerPort==39212==
osReleaseId==rhel==
arch==x86_64==
webUiAccessToken====
cc11e6e5-2b75-47ea-a727-62f738a7b5d9: end
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 5: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I am not sure what the `channel 5: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed` is about. Based on my research, some have implied this is related to the fact that SSH Port forwarding is disabled on the jumpbox, while others aren't convinced.

Networking is not my strong suite. I would love to hear from the community on what the issue might be.